# A guess on two increasing rational approximations to $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, approximation, hypergeometric-function, approximation-theory

When investigated the Wilf function
$$W(z)=\frac{\arctan\sqrt{2\operatorname{e}^{-z}-1}\,}{\sqrt{2\operatorname{e}^{-z}-1}\,},$$
see the preprint [1] below, I proposed a guess which reads that the sequences
\begin{equation}\label{approx2pi-guess-qi}\tag{QG}
\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1} \sum_{\ell=0}^{k-j-1}\binom{k}{\ell}
=-\frac{1}{\binom{2k}{k}}\sum_{\ell=1}^{k} (-1)^{\ell} \binom{2k-\ell}{k} \frac{2^{\ell/2}}{\ell} \sin\frac{3\ell\pi}{4}
\end{equation}
are increasing in $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and tend to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ as $k\to\infty$.

If this guess were verified to be true, then the sequences in \eqref{approx2pi-guess-qi} would be two increasing rational approximations of the irrational constant $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

This guess is also related to a closed-form formula of the Gauss hypergeometric series ${}_2F_1\bigl(k+\frac12,k+1;k+\frac32;-z^2\bigr)$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$, which is established in a forthcoming paper authored by me.

**Question**: is the above guess true?

1. Feng Qi and Mark Daniel Ward, *Closed-form formulas and properties of coefficients in Maclaurin’s series expansion of Wilf’s function composited by inverse tangent, square root, and exponential functions*, arXiv (2022), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08576v2.

Comment: An interesting problem; I failed at the first attempt :) Is complicated by the fact that we are dealing with a strongly alternating series. I will see whether I can do something here, though...

Comment: The identity $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1}=\frac\pi4$$ may be useful.